# crystal reports 2008 installation failed on windows 8

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

this is my error log

[04/14/13,16:28:11] Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 64bit Prerequisites (x64): [2] g:\setup..\wcu\64bitprereq\x64\vs_bsln.exe could not be unpackaged because it is not a cabinet.
[04/14/13,16:28:12] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
[04/14/13,16:28:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 64bit Prerequisites (x64) is not installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:12] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Document Explorer 2008 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 3.5 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for the Microsoft Office system (version 3.0 Runtime) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:13] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Design Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 For Devices was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2 for Pocket PC was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2 for Smartphone was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Device Emulator version 3.0 (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Remote Debugger (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:14] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports Basic 64-Bit Runtime for Visual Studio 2008 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Headers and Libraries (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Win32 Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 .NET Framework Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 SDK Reference Assemblies and IntelliSense (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:28:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:07] Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 64bit Prerequisites (x64): [2] g:\setup..\wcu\64bitprereq\x64\vs_bsln.exe could not be unpackaged because it is not a cabinet.
[04/14/13,16:47:08] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
[04/14/13,16:47:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 64bit Prerequisites (x64) is not installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Document Explorer 2008 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 2.0 SP2 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Compact Framework 3.5 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for the Microsoft Office system (version 3.0 Runtime) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Tools for the 2007 Microsoft Office System Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 Design Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:09] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 For Devices was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2 for Pocket PC was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2 for Smartphone was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Device Emulator version 3.0 (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Remote Debugger (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports Basic 64-Bit Runtime for Visual Studio 2008 was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:10] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Headers and Libraries (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Win32 Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 .NET Framework Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 SDK Reference Assemblies and IntelliSense (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[04/14/13,16:47:11] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard was not attempted to be installed.
[04/17/13,23:49:01] Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008. MSI returned error code 1603
***EndOfSession***�﻿[06/18/13,13:58:58] Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008. MSI returned error code 1603
***EndOfSession***�﻿[06/18/13,14:37:04] Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008. MSI returned error code 1603
***EndOfSession***�﻿[06/18/13,14:37:04] Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008. MSI returned error code 1603
[06/18/13,14:37:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008 is not installed.
[06/18/13,14:37:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports Basic 64-Bit Runtime for Visual Studio 2008 was not attempted to be installed.
[06/18/13,14:37:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[06/18/13,14:37:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Headers and Libraries (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[06/18/13,14:37:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 Win32 Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[06/18/13,14:37:06] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 .NET Framework Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[06/18/13,14:37:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Windows SDK for Visual Studio 2008 SDK Reference Assemblies and IntelliSense (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[06/18/13,14:37:07] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard was not attempted to be installed.
[06/18/13,14:48:47] Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008: [2] Error: Installation failed for component Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008. MSI returned error code 1603
***EndOfSession***�

Comment: Do you pretend us to check this log? Please show some effort.

Comment: Hi there, the reason the log is pasted there is that i do not understand it and i need help